# PhpStorm ShortCut create a function

Tags: php, keyboard-shortcuts, shortcut

I remember that I saw in a video that you can "unsplit" a part of a function to create the other one but I don't remember how I can do that ...

Example: I have a function that creates a user with an avatar and I want a shortcut for :

1. "Cut" the upload part in that function
2. Create a new function that does the upload
3. Call it where I cut it

I know that is possible so if you know how we can do that thank's

Comment: Depends on the OS you are using; when you right-click on the selected code-block and follow `Refactor > Extract > Method` you will see what the shortcut is.

Comment: https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/extract-method.html

Comment: thx a lot i dind't know that it was called  like this

Comment: Shortcut is: `ALT + ENTER`

Comment: No it's Ctrl + Alt + M (or cmd for apple)